# Trying to read in an external file into a dictionary

Tags: python, syntax

OK I am trying to read in an external file into a dictionary however I am receiving some syntax errors. The clues which get read in then have to replace the letters which they pair with in the list of coded words

My code for reading into a dictionary and replacing the symbols is as follows.

```
d = {}
def read_clues(clues):
    global d
    with open("hey.txt") as f:
        for line in f:
            (key, val) = line[1], line[0]
            d[key] = val


def replace_symbols(clues, words):
    global d
    for word in range(len(words)):
        for key, value in d.items():
            words[word] = words[word].replace(key, value)
```

In the main part of my program I have the code for calling the replace_symbols. However I am getting a syntax error after print key, in the last line. The code for this is shown below.

```
#REPLACES LETTERS 
print("======== The clues have been replaced ===========")
replace_symbols(clues, words) 
for key, value in d.items():
    print key, value // This will print the symbols and letters
```

Comment: Try reading the full error message (all of it) it usually tells you exactly where the problem lies - try thinking of why that part might be a syntax error

Comment: Also, if you want help with a particular error, you have to _post_ the full error message, not just describe it vaguely. The error (or other output) is part of your [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), not just the code.

Comment: Also, what version of Python are you using? You're mixing Python 3's `print` function and Python 2's `print` statement. If you're on Python 3, the latter will be a `SyntaxError`. If you're on Python 2, they'll both work, but the function style may give unexpected results in various cases (e.g., `print(1, 2)` will print the tuple `(1, 2)` instead of printing `1 2`).

Comment: Please do not post duplicate questions you have already been warned about this first...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `hey.txt` has the keys and values separated by a **space**, the following code should work:

```
def read_clues(clues):
    global d
    with open("hey.txt") as f:
        for line in f:
            stuff = line.split(" ") #split each line into parts
            (key, val) = stuff[1], stuff[0]
            d[key] = val
```

If the separator is other than a space, just include it as an argument to `split()`.

Comment: What about for replacing the clues?

Comment: Tell me the exact error that you're getting.

Comment: for fw_line, fs_line in (fw, fs):
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Comment: Give more context. What is fw, fs? What's next? BTW, your syntax is wrong.

Comment: Sorry wrong error, the error which i am getting is this...   (key, val) = stuff[1], stuff[0]
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: How is hey.txt formatted?

Comment: This is solving something that's almost certainly a problem in the asker's code… but it doesn't solve the actual problem he's asking about, and he won't even be able to get to the point where this matters until he gets past the `SyntaxError`, so it's not really an answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are some other problems in your code, but since you're asking about the syntax error, it's almost certainly this line:

```
print key, value // This will print the symbols and letters
```

First, `//` does not mean "comment" in Python, it means "integer division". So, you're asking it to divide `value` by `This` (which would probably raise a `NameError`, because it's unlikely you have anything named `This` in your code), and then including a bunch of other identifiers starting with `will`. A string of two identifiers in a row isn't valid syntax.

How *do* you write a comment in Python? Use `#`, not `//`:

```
print key, value # This will print the symbols and letters
```

Second, if you're using Python 3.x, `print` is a normal function, like anything else, so its arguments have to go in parentheses, like all of your other function calls. (And given the `print` call a few lines up, I'm willing to bet you *are* using Python 3.x.) Most likely you've copied this from some code for Python 2.x. There are some important differences between Python 2 and 3, which means that not all code for Python 2 can be copied and pasted into your Python 3. And this is one of the cases where it doesn't work. So:

```
print(key, value) # This will print the symbols and letters
```

But *don't* make that second change if you're using Python 2.x; otherwise, you'll just end up printing a tuple instead of two strings separated by a space. (For example, `print 1, 2` prints `1 2`, but `print(1, 2)` prints `(1, 2)`.)